# antlr rule priorities and missing token

Tags: antlr4

Regarding this grammar :

```
CHAR  : ([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ0-9] | '.' | '_') ;
COLON : (':') ;
prefix: ('a' | 'b') ;
word  : (CHAR)+ ;
nested: prefix COLON word ;
item  : word ;
input : ( WS | nested | word)* ;
```

And this input :

```
gef a:test abc
```

I would like to parse abc like a "word" but with this grammar, "abc" matches the "nested" pattern (with a "missing:COLON" warning)

How to avoid "abc" to match "prefix COLON word" rule ?

Thanks
Franck

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to remove the ambiguity. Perhaps the simplest is to fully characterize prefixes:

```
input : ( nested | word)* EOF ;
nested: PREFIX word ;
word  : CHAR+ ;

PREFIX: 'a:' | 'b:' ;
CHAR  : [a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ0-9] | '.' | '_' ;
WS    : [ \r\n\t]+ -> skip ;
```

**Added:**

The ambiguity in the OP grammar is due to the fact that both the `CHAR` rule and the implicit lexer rule generated for the `prefix` rule both match the initial `a` in `abc`.

ANTLR generates implicit lexer rules for every string literal specified in the parser. These implicit rules are placed logically at the top of the lexer grammar/before any of the explicit lexer rules. At least, this is how ANTLR has and currently operates (there is no official ANTLR specification on this, so it is all a tool implementation detail).

The lexer will run to completion before the parser runs. Consequently, the `a` is likely being tokenized as a token named something like `T__a` (the name of the implicit lexer rule) and not `CHAR` as expected.

Best advice is to never use string literals in the parser.

Comment: Actually in the "true" grammar this is what I did. But I would like to have a better understanding of why there is an ambiguity, as "abc" doesn't match 'a|b' ':' [a-z]*